# How to support iOS 7 before it's available to public?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I have an app on App-Store. I noticed some bugs on iOS7 Beta and fixed those bugs with XCode5 DP with some new iOS7 methods. Now I can't publish to App-Store since it doesn't accept with new iOS7 SDK. But I have to update my app before iOS7 goes public, so my users won't experience bad behavior.

How can I do that? Will we be allowed to publish our apps before iOS7 releases?

Comment: Apple will start accepting iOS7 builds ~ 2 weeks before public release. This is your window to get the app updated before the public release.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix that and submit the app using old Xcode. 
There is no way you cannot fix that using the old Xcode, if you have a very good reason (I can't think of one) you should wait to new Xcode 5 stable release. I assume on 10 Sep Apple would accept new versions and after that they would work around the clock to approve all new updates due to new OS (it's approx. 2 weeks). So if you submit on the 10th or even a week later you would be ready on time.